# Bayesian method for computing credibility interval for correlated time series

Tags: time-series, bayesian, bootstrap

I'm studying a stochastic process generated by simulation using two different methods. In the first, the waiting time between events can be shown to be exponentially distributed. To model the credibility interval for the rate of events, $k$, I'm using an analytic form of the posterior distribution generated with a uniform prior:

$P(k{\vert}n, T) = \frac{T^{n+1}}{n!}k^nexp(-kT)$

which is a two-parameter gamma function in $k$. Here $n$ is the number of observed events and $T$ is the total time required to observe those events.

The second method generates the same maximum likelihood rate $k$, but the underlying process is not Poisson, and has unknown/ill-defined noise. Additionally the arrival of events is strongly correlated. Traditionally I would analyze the confidence interval on the rate using a block boostrap, with block size chosen to be longer than the correlation time of arrival events.

The confidence interval from the bootstrap is a different statistical object than the credible interval from the posterior distribution so I'm trying to figure out the following:

What is an appropriate way to calculate a credible region for the second method in a Bayesian framework? I'm aware of Rubin's Bayesian Bootstrap, but I wasn't sure if that would be appropriate drop-in replacement for the standard Bootstrap that I've employed previously.